# In Oracle how to search with sub conditions on same column

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle how do I find Cars which must have Feature1 and have at lest, one out of Feature2 or Feature3. Sample table and expected result should look like below screenshot.  Thanks Kiran [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select t1.car, t1.feature
from yourtable t1
inner join
(  -- inner select returns the cars with the Feature1 and Feature2 or Feature3
  select car, feature
  from yourtable 
  where feature = 'Feature1'
    and exists (select car
                from yourtable 
                where feature in ('Feature2', 'Feature3'))
) t2
  on t1.car = t2.car
where t1.feature in ('Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3') -- this excludes any other features
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20172/15)

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this with GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
select car
from t
group by car
having max(case when feature = 'Feature1' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when feature in ('Feature1', 'Feature2') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

This query returns the cars.  To get the featuers as well, you have to join tis back in:

```
select t.*
from (select car
      from t
      group by car
      having max(case when feature = 'Feature1' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
             max(case when feature in ('Feature1', 'Feature2') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
     ) c join
     t
     on t.car = c.car
```

I like this method, because the same idea can be used for handling many different similar queries -- AND conditions, OR conditions, different subgroups, and different counts.